# How to assign a named array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, I'm still something of a beginner. This is the exercise:

```
function exerciseOne(classmates){    
// Exercise One: You will be given an array called 'classmates'    
// Create a variable called 'howManyStudents', and assign it to     
// the length of the classmates array (using the length property)
```

And this is my answer:

```
let howManyStudents = classmates;
console.log(classmates.length);
```

when I try to run the test it says "expected answer ['a','b','c','d','e'] to be 5". If it were ['a','b','c','d','e'] I would be fine, but the way it's written as a name and not an array has me a little confused.

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

edit: that worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the classmates.length property to the variable

```
function exerciseOne(classmates){
 let howManyStudents = classmates.length;
 console.log(howManyStudents);

 return howManyStudents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning the length of classmates to howManyStudents variable, you are assigning the data of classmates to howManyStudents not the length of the classmates.

Should be:

```
let howManyStudents = classmates.length;
console.log(howManyStudents);
```